# How to expand my cell without losing information

Tags: matlab

I have this a cell that holds 4 vectors, and I'd like to expand it so it could hold another vector. Thanks in advance.

```
a = cell(4, 1);
a{1} = [1, 2, 3];
a{2} = [1, 4, 9];
a{3} = [1, 4, 9];
a{4} = [1; 5];
```

And I would like to add a new vector [2, 7] so that I will get this

```
a{1} = [2, 7];
a{2} = [1, 2, 3];
a{3} = [1, 4, 9];
a{4} = [1, 4, 9];
a{5} = [1; 5];
```

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = cell(4, 1);
a{1} = [1, 2, 3];
a{2} = [1, 4, 9];
a{3} = [1, 4, 9];
a{4} = [1; 5];

a = [[2, 7];a]
```

Yielding:

```
a = 

    [1x2 double]
    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]
    [2x1 double]
```

Answer (score 1):

The name for what you are trying to do is [concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html). In MATLAB, [square brackets](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html) are an implicit method of concatenation. While you typically think about these being used to concatenate numbers to form a vector or matrix:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]   % 1 x 4
```

You can also use them to concatenate other data types (including cell arrays)

```
y = [{1,2}, 5, {4, 5}];  % 1 x 3 Cell Array
```

It is also important to keep track of the **dimension** of concatenation. With square brackets you can either concatenate across the columns (2nd dimension) using a comma or across the rows (1st dimension using a semi-colon).

```
size([1,2,3])

1 x 3

size([1;2;3])

3 x 1
```

While square brackets are a quick and easy solution, I prefer to be a little more explicit. For this, MATLAB has the following functions: [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html), [`horzcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html), and [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html). I personally prefer `cat` since you can specify concatenation in any arbitrary dimension.

```
x = cat(2, 100, 200, 300);    % 1 x 3

    100   200   300

x = cat(1, 100, 200, 300);    % 3 x 1

    100
    200
    300

x = cat(3, 100, 200, 300)   % 1 x 1 x 3

    x(:,:,1) =

       100

    x(:,:,2) =

       200

    x(:,:,3) =

       300
```

So back to your original question, you want to concatenate in the 1st dimension (rows) so you could simply do the following:

```
a = cell(4, 1);
a{1} = [1, 2, 3];
a{2} = [1, 4, 9];
a{3} = [1, 4, 9];
a{4} = [1; 5];

a = cat(1, [2, 7], a);
```

Also remember that this form of using `concat` or the square brackets can be applied to most datatypes within MATLAB including `struct`s among others.